# Is there a way to find the average of a php variable from a database table?

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to generate an average line on my line chart.

I tried the following code but it is not working, i would like to plot the average of $tit.

How can i alter my code to achieve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['id', 'TIT','Average'],
        <?php
        $query = "select id,tit1,avg(tit1) as average_tit from engine2";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
          $id = $data["id"];
          $tit = $data["tit1"];
          $avg = $data["average_tit"];
          
          
        ?>
          ['<?php echo $id; ?>', <?php echo $tit; ?>, <?php echo $avg; ?>],
        
        <?php 
      } 
      ?>
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'T5',
        // curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart3'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
```

[Single Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt456.png)

Comment: Why not just `SELECT AVG(tit) FROM engine2`

Comment: @AlexHowansky new to php, where would i put this query?

Comment: You're sending the query `select * from engine2` and then calculating the average of all the rows yourself. You can throw away all of that code and instead send the query `select avg(tit) from engine` -- the database will calculate the average for you and just return that one value.

Comment: You can't calculate the average during the loop. You calculate the average after the loop is done, by dividing the total of the column by the number of rows.

Comment: `array_sum($tit)` makes no sense, since `$tit` isn't an array. It's just the value of the `tit` column in the current row.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way I can get all the values for "$tit" and put them in an array during the loop?

Comment: Sure. `$tit_array[] = $tit;` will push the value onto the array. Then at the end you can use `array_sum($tit_array) / count($tit_array)`.

Comment: @Barmar i tried this, thanks! but the line it generates isnt a straight line for some reason. Please check the picture i have put up.

Comment: There's no picture

Comment: hey @Barmar i added the pic now

Comment: @AlexHowansky if i use the statement "select avg(tit) from engine". how then do i get the $id and $tit because i need to also plot them on my graph. the graph should have average(tit), tit and id

Comment: @mawungwa2  You can write query like this :  select id,tit,avg(tit) as average_tit from engine2

Comment: @ChiragAshara if i use that query, its adding the average on my graph as a single point. I want it to be a continuous line.

Comment: Using `AVG()` in your query causes implicit GROPU BY behavior - you are only _getting_ one single record in your result set now, so you are getting only one single point on your graph as well. Select only `id,tit1`, then loop over the data once, and calculate the average of the `tit1` values in PHP. Then loop a second time, to create the output you need to pass this to the chart.

Comment: If you're showing an average, why do you need a chart, it's just a single number?

Comment: What is on the X axis?